# Problem understanding the behaviour of std::map try_emplace for a composite key

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++17, emplace

I have a `std::map<CompositeKey, std::string>`, where `CompositeKey` is a class I wrote.
This `CompositeKey` has three `int` data members, all the constructors, all the copy assignment operators and a `friend bool operator<`, which compares the sum of the three data members.

I understood how to use `emplace` and `emplace_hint`.

For example:

```
// emplace
std::map<CompositeKey, std::string> my_map;
int first_id = 10, second_id = 100, third_id = 1000;
std::string my_string = "foo";
auto [ insertedIt, success ] = my_map.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,     
                                              std::forward_as_tuple(first_id, second_id, third_id), 
                                              std::forward_as_tuple(my_string));
// emplace_hint
first_id = 5, second_id = 50, third_id = 500;
my_string = "bar";
std::tie(insertedIt, success) = my_map.emplace_hint(insertedIt
                                                    std::piecewise_construct,     
                                                    std::forward_as_tuple(first_id, second_id, third_id), 
                                                    std::forward_as_tuple(my_string));
```

The only way I was able to use `try_emplace` was in the version without hint:

```
first_id = 1, second_id = 10, third_id = 100;
my_string = "foobar";
std::tie(insertedIt, success) = my_map.try_emplace({first_id, second_id, third_id},
                                                   my_string);
```

My questions are:

1. Is this the only way to call `try_emplace`, without hint? If not, how could I call it?
2. How could I call the `try_emplace` version with a hint? I made some attempts but always failed.
3. Is it correct to assume that `try_emplace` "move" or "copy" the CompositeKey inside the map? I am asking about the behaviour of `try_emplace` both because I read something similar on another discussion, and because I wrote a verbose copy and move constructors to make a test.

I am sorry, I made my research but do not understand these points from the [cppreference documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/try_emplace)

Comment: `try_emplace(insertedIt,` - That's a hint.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica It was an error writing the message, sorry! I corrected my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the cppreference documentation. In your code, you are always trying to add a key that is not in the map. And you are passing that key as an lvalue reference. The only difference with your two cases is that you are using a hint in the second call. So the two `try_emplace` versions you are using, according to cppreference, are 1 and 3.

> ```
> template< class... Args > pair<iterator, bool> try_emplace( const Key& k, Args&&... args ); (1)   (since C++17)
>
> template< class... Args > iterator try_emplace( const_iterator hint, const Key& k, Args&&... args ); (3)  (since C++17)
> ```

Notice:

- Both versions receive the key as an lvalue reference (**`Key&`**).
- First version returns a `pair<iterator, bool`, but second version just returns an `iterator`.

Now, the text below doesn't tell how you have to build your `try_emplace` arguments; instead, it says what `try_emplace` is doing internally.

> ```
> 1) If a key equivalent to k already exists in the container, does nothing.
>    Otherwise, behaves like emplace except that the element is constructed as
>
> value_type(std::piecewise_construct,
>            std::forward_as_tuple(k),
>            std::forward_as_tuple(std::forward<Args>(args)...))
> ```

In short, just call `try_emplace` passing a `CompositeKey` object and a string as arguments (and, optionally, an iterator as a hint). The code below calls `try_emplace` with an lvalue and an rvalue (the second call with a hint), so it would use the versions 1 and 4.

[[Demo]](https://godbolt.org/z/WjnT7edMn)

```cpp
std::map<CompositeKey, std::string> my_map;

std::cout << "Case 1:\n";
auto key1{CompositeKey{10, 100, 1000}};
auto value1{std::string{"foo"}};
auto [insertedIt, success] = my_map.try_emplace(key1, value1);

std::cout << "Case 2:\n";
insertedIt = my_map.try_emplace(insertedIt, {5, 50, 500}, "bar");

// Outputs:
//
//   Case 1:
//       custom ctor
//       copy ctor
//   Case 2:
//       custom ctor
//       move ctor
```

> 3. Is it correct to assume that try_emplace "move" or "copy" the CompositeKey inside the map?

Whatever you pass is forwarded to `try_emplace` implementation. In the example above, both `CompositeKey` arguments are first "custom constructed" ; then, they are passed to `try_emplace`, where the lvalue is copy constructed while the rvalue is move constructed.

Comment: The first to calls are to ```emplace``` and to ```emplace_hint```. Only the third one is a call to ```try_emplace```

Comment: OK, I thought your problem was mainly with `try_emplace`. Anyway, whatever function you use, just pass `CompositeKey`s and strings are arguments. The only possible optimization I see is to pass `char*` instead of strings as rvalue arguments, so you save a string move.

Comment: Yes, my problem is with ```try_emplace```. The first two calls behave as expected, i.e. they emplace the elements in the map. Give me the time to check your kind suggestion about ```try_emplace``` and I will give you a feedback. :)

Comment: Perfect! I found the error in my code. I was calling ```try_emplace``` like you suggested... but I was still assigning its return value to ```std::tie(insertedIt, success)``` and not to just ```insertedIt```. The problem itself was not in the call, but in the fact that I was assigning the return value not properly. Many thanks again for your help!

Comment: Oh sorry, yes, I forgot to comment that on my answer. I'll update it. I'm glad it's working now.